# Object manipulation in PowerShell

Tags: csv, powershell

Is there a way to manipulate the content of the `Object` so that the output shows the applications present on DESKTOP A?

```
$DB_struct = Import-Csv -Path $path
$DB_struct =

bundle              app
DESKTOP A            A
DESKTOP A            B
DESKTOP A            C
DESKTOP A            D
DESKTOP B            E
DESKTOP B            F
DESKTOP B            G
DESKTOP B            H
DESKTOP C            I
DESKTOP C            J
DESKTOP C            K
DESKTOP C            L
```

EDIT: Changed `Export-Csv` to `Import-Csv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you mean `Import-Csv` and not `Export-Csv`.

```
$DB_struct | Where-Object { $_.bundle -eq 'DESKTOP A' } | Select-Object -Property app
```

Although, depending on what you're doing, you might need:

```
$DB_struct | Where-Object { $_.bundle -eq 'DESKTOP A' } | Select-Object -ExpandProperty app
```